# Will redis lua scripting increase read performance in this case?

Tags: redis, lua

Let's suppose that we have simplified online store with following entities: products, related products and categories. Relations are pretty simple:

- Products are linked to categories
- Products have related products
- Products prices are region specific

All entities are stored as json strings in Redis, something like:

Products (and related products): `{"productId":1, "title": "Product", "relatedProductIds":[4,5,6], "categoryIds":[1,2,3]}`

Product prices: `{"price": 555.5, "region": "eu"}`

Category: `{"categoryId": 12, "title": "Category"}`

Our task is to fetch **whole tree from redis** for some product ids: products, products categories, products prices, product related products, categories of related products, related products prices. Doing this from client is okay, but requires multiple requests to redis. Whole procedure could be described in this way:

- Fetch all required products and prices and json decode them. Now we know list of primary products categories and related product ids.
- Fetch categories, related products and prices of related products and json decode them. Now we know list of related products categories.
- Fetch related products categories.

It works and it works really fast, but could this be done using redis lua scripting? I'm planning to do this job via lua, combine one big json (or multiple small jsons) and return to client. Is it worth doing and why?

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: Are you running on a single Redis or clustered Redis?

Comment: @GuyKorland Hello! All entities are stored on single instance, but we have multiple copies of instances and balance between them. So, no need to go to another instance to find some entity, all required entities could be found at the same instance.

Comment: Are these the real JSON structure you store or do they hold many more fields you might not need to retrieve?

Comment: @GuyKorland no, it is a simplified. We have more entities with more fields, but I can create light keys that only have relations, for example - it is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lua script should probably get you much better latency than couple of hopes.
Especially if you don't need to retrieve all the fields, this way you should reduce data load on network and return only the relevant fields.

BTW, you might want to check https://redisgears.io and https://redisjson.io in case you have more complex use cases, that might require supporting Redis Cluster or more complex JSONs.

Comment: Thank you! Frankly speaking I was even thinking about totally avoiding json decode in lua for fetching relation ids. Simple regexps could be used as well.

Comment: RedisJson is really interesting. Is it production ready?

Answer (score 0):

Lua script performance depends on what you did inside script. As Redis uses single thread command executor, if your script execute for a long time, it will block other commands and make Redis slower for response.

For your case I would recommend to query the different data directly from Redis and handle their relations in your application. In this way, Redis is only used for data storage not for logic, and make it pure and faster.